# How do I 'refactor' SQL Queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design, refactoring

I have several MS Access queries (in views and stored procedures) that I am converting to SQL Server 2000 (T-SQL).  Due to Access's limitations regarding sub-queries, and or the limitations of the original developer, many views have been created that function only as sub-queries for other views.

I don't have a clear business requirements spec, except to 'do what the Access application does', and half a page of notes on reports/CSV extracts, but the Access application doesn't even do what I suspect is required properly.

I, therefore, have to take a bottom up approach, and 'copy' the Access DB to T-SQL, where I would normally have a better understanding of requirements and take a top down approach, creating new queries to satisfy well defined requirements.

Is there a method I can follow in doing this?  Do I spread it all out and spend a few days 'grokking' it, or do I continue just copying the Access views and adopt an evolutionary approach to optimising the querying?

Comment: I'll bet you find some bugs in those access views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work out what access does with the queries, and then use this knowledge to check that you've transferred it properly. Only once you've done this can you think about refactoring. I'd start with slow queries and then go from there: work out what indexes you need and then progressively rewrite. This way you can deliver as soon as you've proved that you moved everything successfully (even if it is potentially a bit slower). That's much better than not being able to deliver at all because problem X came along.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably start with the Access database, exercise the queries in situ and see what the resultset is. Often you can understand what the query accomplishes and then work back to your own design to accomplish it. (To be thorough, you'll need to understand the intent pretty completely anyway.) And that sounds like the best statement of requirements you're going to get - "Just like it's implemented now."

Other than that, You're approach is the best I can think of. Once they are in SQL Server, just start testing and grokking.

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with a problem like this it's often helpful to keep things working as they are while you make incremental changes.  This is better from a risk management perspective.

I'd concentrate on getting it working, then checking the database performance and optimizing performance problems.  Then, as you add features and fix bugs, clean up the code that's hard to maintain.  As you said, a sub-query is really very similar to a view.  So if it's not broken you may not need to change it.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your timeline. If you have to get the project running absolutely as soon as possible (I know this is true for EVERY project, but if it's REALLY true for you), then yes, duplicate the functionality and infrastructure from Access then do your refactoring either later or as you go.

If you have SOME time you can dedicate to it, then refactoring it now will give you two things:

1. You'll be happier with the code, and it will (likely) perform better, since actual analysis was done rather than the transcoding equivalent of a copy-paste
2. You'll likely gain a greater understanding of what the true business rules are, since you'll almost certainly come across things that aren't in the spec (especially considering how you describe them)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend copying the views to SQL Server immediately, and then use its sophisticated tools to help you grok them.

For example, SQL Server can tell you what views, stored procedures, etc, rely on a particular view, so you can see from there whether the view is a one-of or if it's actually used in more than one place. It will help you determine which views are more important than which.